# How to fix Import object_detection/protos/image_resizer.proto but not used

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection-api, protobuf-python

I have an issue when I try to compile Protobuf to use TensorFlow Object Detection API.

I'm following this tutorial: https://github.com/Khaivdo/How-to-train-an-Object-Detector-using-Tensorflow-API-on-Ubuntu-16.04-GPU

In the command line I tried to launch this command (1.4.2 Compile Protobuf in the tutorial link):

```
# From ObjectDetection/models/research/
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

And I got this error:

```
object_detection/protos/input_reader.proto: warning: Import object_detection/protos/image_resizer.proto but not used.
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/8954) issue, this is just an internal **warning** (not an error) and it should not bother you. You can follow along with your execution.